# Implement scraping of page in chunks in Scrapy Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to **scrape** webpage in Scrapy but in chunks. The goal is just to read the title of the page, not the full page.

Ex. If I have a page size 150KB but I just wanted to read the title that must be in the upper part and under 10KB of page size so if I read the first part I am gonna find the title and just cancel the remaining page **scraping**.

Is it possible to implement something in Scrapy so read the page in chunks?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do a such thing. Have you done something by your own ? If yes, show it to us.

Comment: This feels like a duplicate of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59541755/how-to-decrease-the-bandwidth-of-scraping-pages-via-scrapy)

Comment: Search about `Range` header

Comment: @Gallaecio previous question is also about to remove images, css, js or any other files to reduce the bandwidth. In this question, I am just focusing on the reduce bandwidth via page size.

Comment: @codrelphi I didn't do anything yet. I don't know where to start.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy does not currently support stopping the reading of a response before it has finished.

You might want to monitor some of the related existing feature requests:

- [Provide DownloaderMiddleware an interface to read raw HTTP requests and responses](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/440)
- [More possibilities to cancel downloads inside HTTP downloader handler](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1772)

It may also make sense to create a new feature request that focuses on your scenario, since you want to stop reading a response but still get the data read so far in your callbacks, which I don’t think is covered in existing feature requests.